# Using themes in visio

Tags: themes, microsoft-visio

I'm looking for a good reference on how to properly use themes in Visio.  Here's been my experience so far:

1. Create a flowchart diagram - nothing fancy, just all black & white. No formatting applied to any object.
2. Select & apply a theme to the diagram.  Despite the theme showing a set of matching colors, the diagram now has a **single** color applied to all objects.
3. Right-click the object, format, fill, and pick a color from the set of matching theme colors.
4. End up with an amalgamation of the original theme color I picked (blue) and the new color (green).

With enough 'playing' with the object, I can get it to look OK, but it feels like I'm missing something, that it shouldn't be this hard to get a matching color. Any advice would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the stencils themselves only have basic color theming functionality unless they're designed to support the "interface".  i.e. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445858.aspx#Visio2007DesigningShapes_AnatomyofaShape) talks about the details.

I agree about the clunkiness of it - I would guess it's a feature that can/should grow in usefulness over time.  For example, I'd love it if the color blending would happen at the layer level (e.g. a box within a box gets a different color than its layer below).

But you can see the potential if you create a Work Flow Diagram - those shapes support the advanced theme coloring.